# Only include emails once in SQL query

Tags: sql, sapb1

Having a bit of a dead brain moment right now.

I have this query to give me BP Codes,Names, Contacts and Sales Person. I only want to include an existing email once in the query. If the same email exists for multiple BP's then only 1 BP should be included (lets say TOP 1).

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
OCRD.CardCode, 
OCRD.CardName,
OCPR.Name,
OCPR.E_MailL,
OSLP.SlpName
FROM OCRD 
INNER JOIN OCRG ON OCRG.GroupCode = OCRD.GroupCode 
INNER JOIN OCPR ON OCPR.CardCode = OCRD.CardCode
INNER JOIN OOND ON OOND.IndCode = OCRD.IndustryC 
INNER JOIN OSLP ON OCRD.SlpCode = OSLP.SlpCode 
WHERE OCRG.GroupName <> 'Retail'  AND 
OOND.IndName = 'Aged Care' and 
OCRD.frozenFor = 'N' AND
OCPR.E_MailL LIKE '%@%'
ORDER BY OCRD.CardCode ASC
```

For the life of me I cant figure it out right now. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group) stackoverflow post, I assume this might work

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (OCPR.E_MailL)
OCRD.CardCode, 
OCRD.CardName,
OCPR.Name,
OCPR.E_MailL,
OSLP.SlpName
FROM OCRD 
INNER JOIN OCRG ON OCRG.GroupCode = OCRD.GroupCode 
INNER JOIN OCPR ON OCPR.CardCode = OCRD.CardCode
INNER JOIN OOND ON OOND.IndCode = OCRD.IndustryC 
INNER JOIN OSLP ON OCRD.SlpCode = OSLP.SlpCode 
WHERE OCRG.GroupName <> 'Retail'  AND 
OOND.IndName = 'Aged Care' and 
OCRD.frozenFor = 'N' AND
OCPR.E_MailL LIKE '%@%'
ORDER BY OCRD.CardCode ASC, OCRD.E_MAIL
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @WithThee, it doesnt appear that DISTINCT ON works in SAP B1 for SQL.

Comment: This does not work on HANA Sql script, shows error 'sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "ON"'.